# Can an Admin Access Pending Subscriptions in MailChimp?

Tags: mailchimp, subscriptions

I'm testing a change to my custom confirmation thank you page. I use a signup form and the confirmation opt in reCHAPTCHA page. I accidentally closed the confirmation opt in reCHAPTCHA page before responding. The link is not in my history so I cannot access it. I would like to either reproduce the link so I can respond to it or delete that email from the mailing list.

I did a search in the MailChimp help section of the website but could not find anything. I have also done web searches but have not found any posts related to this issue. I have a free MailChimp account so I do not have access to any help other than online help.

Comment: Why is this question being considered for closing?

Comment: Because it is unrelated to programming?

Comment: Because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Okay that's true! Feel free to delete the question.